# is there any tool/app to retrieve all the pdf listed in my bibtex and put/copy them into one folder?

Tags: bibliographies

I have collected a bunch of publications in pdf format and put them into some folders based on the topic. 
Now I have finished the report and only use ~70 of them.
They are listed in bibtex file.

As the title says, I would like to collect only the pdfs that I use and put them in one folder.
Is there any tool/app to do that?
It is even better if they can be sorted based on their appearance in my bibliography, e.g., by adding number in their file name.

I can copy/paste them manually but I am hoping there is a tool to do that automatically.

Comment: How should the tool detect folder and file name based on your bibliography?

Comment: what I have is one main folder that contains some folders that are named after the topics. All pdf already have the title as its name.  in my mind, this app can see the title in the bibtex and look it up in the main folder. off course I have to give the path to the main folder to this tool.

Comment: This will certainly depend on the operating system, e.g. macOS or Windows or iOS or other. You may be better to do the inverse. Find a tool that does a file directory listing with folder designations. Then match the output (manually at first) to your Bibtex list.

Comment: "grep" or "find" `title=` on your bib file may simply list ALL files rather than those you \cited, there are bib managers for some editors but if your asking you probably have not used one. So to my mind the best indicator of your used "list" is the PDF output. Subject to how listed you could possibly cut and paste them from the report or from a copy of report modify to produce a table of sequential referenced titles to make that easier. once you have a list of filenames then simple editing of that list should make it easier to script by name or part thereof

Comment: its possinble one of the ctan packages may help see https://ctan.org/topic/bibtex-util